# python not creating sql / updating file

Tags: python, sql

Okay so i've scoured the web and tried and failed for a few days now.
i see many answers about commit, directory etc... but none of its working

I run the python file and supposedly my bootcamp says it should be updating the sql file.
it didn't create the file as i was under the impression it would so I went ahead and manually created and tried everything again. my python seems to have no effect on the file.

Here's the code i'm using.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('emaildb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Counts')

cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE Counts (org TEXT, count INTEGER)''')

fh = open(r"c:\Users\hotsa\OneDrive\Desktop\code\SQ\mbox.txt")

for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith('From: '): continue
    pieces = line.split()
    email = pieces[1]
    dom = email.find('@')
    org = email[dom + 1: len(email)]
    cur.execute('SELECT count FROM Counts WHERE org = ? ', (org,))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if row is None:
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Counts (org, count)
                VALUES (?, 1)''', (org,))
    else:
        cur.execute('UPDATE Counts SET count = count + 1 WHERE org = ?',
                    (org,))
    conn.commit()

# https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html
sqlstr = 'SELECT org, count FROM Counts ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10'

for row in cur.execute(sqlstr):
    print(str(row[0]), row[1])

cur.close()
```

The picture of the directory
[image of directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTNE1.png)

it seems to run in visual studio codes terminal fine, but just doesn't update the sql file.
what do i do?

Comment: Is it a possibility that the `emaildb.sqlite` file is being written to somewhere other than the directory you show?  What happens if you replace `emaildb.sqlite` with the full path to the database file, i.e. `C:\Users\hotsa\...\emaildb.sqlite`?

Comment: thank you so much, this worked. i don't understand where else it would be going, i checked everywhere and even my search doesn't find it. maybe cause OneDrive???

Comment: You need to call fh.close()

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone,
i appreciate the suggestions and Luke Woodward you were correct, changing it to the direct file path worked, apparently there is a unrecognizable copy somewhere.
I changed
conn = sqlite3.connect('emaildb.sqlite')
to
conn = sqlite3.connect(r"c:\Users\hotsa\OneDrive\Desktop\code\SQ\emaildb.sqlite")

Answer (score -1):

I think there could be some type of security issue where your SQL server won't allow it to be changed by an external code

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'SQL server'.  The questioner is using SQLite, which stores its database in a file.